# google map api key fail

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2, api-key

In the config i define:

```
.config(
    ['uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider', function(GoogleMapApiProviders) {
        GoogleMapApiProviders.configure({
            v: '2.3.3',
            libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization',
            key: 'AIzaSyCz2DCKjoWMnlrf0V23RGidagkYrwTce38'
        });
        }
    ]);
```

And inside the index.html i wrote:

```
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCz2DCKjoWMnlrf0V23RGidagkYrwTce38"></script>
```

The problem is that i get error here:

```
$scope.location = function () {
        window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.position = position.coords;
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                geocoder.geocode({
                    'latLng': {
                        lat: $scope.position.latitude,
                        lng: $scope.position.longitude
                    }
                }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        if (results[0]) {
                            $scope.$apply(function () {
                                $scope.userLocation = results[0].formatted_address;
                            });
                        } else {
                            $scope.$apply(function () {
                                $scope.userLocation = "No se ha podido conseguir la dirección";
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        }, function (error) {
            alert(error);
        });
    };
```

Because google tell me that i didn´t insert the key when as you can see, i did that before

The error is:

```
js?v=3.exp&callback=initGoogleMaps:37 Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error_.hb @ js?v=3.exp&callback=initGoogleMaps:37(anonymous function) @ common.js:51(anonymous function) @ common.js:191c @ common.js:45(anonymous function) @ AuthenticationService.Authenticate?1shttp%3A%2F%2F47.62.226.23%3A9000%2Fangular%2Findex.html%23%2Fs…:1
```

Comment: If you replace version '2.3.3' to '3.20' it should work

Comment: Go on not working. Here is the error:
js?v=3.exp&callback=initGoogleMaps:37 Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#missing-key-map-error_.hb @ js?v=3.exp&callback=initGoogleMaps:37(anonymous function) @ common.js:51(anonymous function) @ common.js:191c @ common.js:45(anonymous function) @ AuthenticationService.Authenticate?1shttp%3A%2F%2F47.62.226.23%3A9000%2Fangular%2Findex.html%23%2Fs…:1

Answer (score 0):

As described in [Error Messages](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages), `MissingKeyMapError` is a developer error code which means that:

> The script element that loads the API is missing the required authentication parameter. If you are using the standard Maps JavaScript API, you must use a key parameter with a valid API key. If you are a Premium Plan customer, you must use either a client parameter with your client ID or a key parameter with a valid API key.

And as suggested, see the guide to [API keys and client IDs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key).

If after checking the API keys given in the documentation and issue still persists, please try the workaround given in [Issue 9975](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9975) in gmaps-api-issues. Encountered problem might also be related to the raised issue.

In addition to that, recent announcement in Geo Developers Blog regarding [Building for Scale: Updates to Google Maps APIs Standard Plan](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.au/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html) might also help.